# input con calendario rango de fechas

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un input con calendario , necesito que permita seleccionar desde hoy a 6 dias atras , la ultima semana seria, hice este codigo pero no me muestra la parte de seleccionar solo ese rango de fechas, aca subo todo el codigo , para mas detalles, lo estoy haciendo con datepicker yo ese codigo lo tengo metido en un archivo .blade.php

desde ya gracias

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 3
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el html? please

Comment: ahi recien lo subi

Answer (score 0):

Podrías implementar esta librería [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) e implementar algo más o menos parecido a esto:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 2000,
    maxDate: "2020/10/10",
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
    alert("You are " + years + " years old!");
  });
});
```

Al configurar el objeto puedes en la propiedad maxDate calcular la fecha actual y restarle los días, y pasarselo para que solo deje seleccionar en ese rango. En la página se ve más clara la explicación.

Comment: si esa libreria estoy usando, pero no me funciona la parte de max y min

Comment: ammm no, son parecidas pero no son las mismas, lo que estás usando es una característica que trae JQuery, la otra es aparte pero depende de JQuery, dale una checada al enlace y verás que varia un poquito.